# What is the cultural centre of Budapest?

Tags: rental, budapest

I'm going to plan a short visit to Budapest (maybe a weekend).

I always use a well known site to rent an apartment with cheap price, and I have to choose the apartment seeing a map.

So which is the cultural centre of Budapest, where would be recommended to rent the house?

EDIT: as cultural centre i mean the major points of the city where people meets, like pubs, discos, baths etc etc...

Comment: What is "cultural center"? Near Opera house or some picture gallery? Have you read something about Budapest at all?

Comment: that's not correct, for example i can say that in Milan (the city i live in) cultural centre SHOULD be around Duomo or Castello sforzesco , but all the social life of the city is rounding near peripheric pubs

Comment: Sorry, what is not correct? I didn't stated anything, I asked questions and questions can not be correct or incorrect.

Comment: asking me if i read something about budapest at all seems like an accuse, if i misuderstood, all my excuses, but that's what i understood

Comment: @Anon he's asking you to define what kind of culture you're looking for as it could be interpreted differently by different people. Budapest has varieties of different things considered _cultural_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the area bordered by Teréz Boulevard, Erzsébet Boulevard, Rákóczi Street, Károly Boulevard, Bajzsi-Zsilinszky Steet. Mostly the inner side of District VII (and a bit of District VI). Sometimes also called "the Party District", because it's a favourite destination of foreigners because of the frequency of bars, pubs, restaurants and ruin pubs. But the area also contains multiple theatres, the Hungarian Opera, so it's also cultural in the classical sense of the term.

Answer (score 2):

Budapest is literally a divided city. The Danube river separates the older Buda from the newer Pest.

The heart of Buda is the Fisherman's Bastion which is also known as the Buda Castle. Within it there is a large concentration of restaurants and bars, plus a number of hotels. This where we chose to stay and everything is a short walking distance away.

Pest is much more ample and has more of everything but not quite as close. Much restaurants and bars are located within a few blocks of Andrassy Boulevard, particularly in the first kilometers starting at the Danube. The boulevard ends in a huge park which holds the Szechenyi thermal baths. By that level though, the concentration of restaurants and bars has diminished. Parallel Kiraly road is also full of bars and restaurant.